# 'app needs to be updated' after updating to iOS 14.5

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

We have received some user feedback that some of our users are running into an issue with the iOS 14.5 update. Unfortunately, we're not sure why this is affecting some people and not others. All of our test devices are running without any issues after the update, so the problem is not as straightforward as it may seem from the error message.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212310

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there any solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: When was the last time you updated your app on the App Store?  Older submissions were re-signed by Apple in preparation for iOS 14.5 but if the user hasn't installed the re-signed app from the App Store it won't run.  Apple would have sent you an email if they were resigning your app

Comment: @Paulw11  Thanks for your reply! The last update time of my app was 2021-04-07, when did Apple send the mail to you? What is the email address for sending the email?

Comment: The email was sent about April 17th. But it only affected apps that haven't been updated for a couple of years.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only solution is to use the App Offload feature:

1. Open **Settings** and navigate to **General > iPad Storage**.
2. Select the app from the list.
3. Tap **Offload App**.
4. After the offload is done, tap **Reinstall App**.

Comment: can you share ss